# Prove $Q_8$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

The following question is from *Abstract Algebra* by Dummit and Foote:

> Prove $Q_8$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_8$.

The following is my attempted proof:

To prove $Q_8$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_8$, we assign the elements $1, -1, i, -i, j, -j, k, -k$ to the integers $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8$, respectively. We then let $Q_8$ act on itself by left multiplication to generate a permutation representation of $Q_8$.

Here are the computations for the representations of $i$ and $j$:

\begin{align}
&i*1 = i &1 \to 3 \\
&i*-1=-i &2 \to 4 \\
&i*i=-1 &3 \to 2 \\
&i*-i=1 &4 \to 1 \\
&i*j=k &5 \to 7 \\
&i*-j=-k &6 \to 8 \\
&i*k=-j &7 \to 6 \\
&i*-k=j &8 \to 5
\end{align}
Therefore, $i$ can be represented as the permutation $(1324)(5768)$.
\begin{align}
&j*1=j&1 \to 5 \\
&j*-1=-j&2 \to 6 \\
&j*i=-k&3 \to 8 \\
&j*-i=k&4 \to 7 \\
&j*j=-1&5 \to 2 \\
&j*-j=1&6 \to 1 \\
&j*k=i&7 \to 3 \\
&j*-k=-i&8 \to 4 \\
\end{align}
Therefore, $j$ can be represented as the permutation $(1526)(3847)$.

We use the presentation $\langle i,j :i^4=j^4=1, i^2*j=j*i^2\rangle$ to show the representations of $i$ and $j$ satisfy the same relations.

Here are the computations:
\begin{align}
[(1324)(5768)]^4 &= [(12)(34)(56)(78)]^2 = 1 \\
[(1526)(3847)]^4 &= [(12)(34)(56)(78)]^2 = 1 \\
&\\
[(1324)(5768)]^2\circ(1526)(3847)&=(12)(34)(56)(78)\circ(1526)(3847) \\
&=(1625)(3748) \\
&=(1526)(3847)\circ(12)(34)(56)(78) \\
&=(1526)(3847)\circ[(1324)(5768)]^2
\end{align}

Thus, the permutation representations of $i$ and $j$ generate a subgroup of $S_8$ that is isomorphic to $Q_8$. $\square$

The conclusion that $Q_8$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_8$ was rather abrupt. It is clear that the representation function has a range of at most eight elements; otherwise, the representation function would not be well-defined. But how can we be certain the range has at least eight elements? Is showing the permutation representations of $i$ and $j$ satisfy the same relations given in the presentation for $Q_8$ sufficient to conclude $Q_8$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_8$?

Comment: Showing that two groups have the same generators and relations shows that they are isomorphic.

Comment: Isn't it necessarily the case that any finite group of order $n$ necessarily embeds into $S_n$?

Comment: ... which is [Cayley's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem).